# Update to Mysql table w/ Inner Join on Information Schema not allowed

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

So I'm trying to update a table that I've created with a join statement to Information schema.
The following is the code that gives the error: `ERROR 3550 (HY000): Information schema queries do not support the 'FOR UPDATE' clause.`

```
UPDATE progress.db_progress dp
 INNER JOIN  information_schema.tables t
 ON dp.table_name = t.TABLE_NAME
 set dp.already_done = (SELECT
   CASE
     WHEN t.TABLE_ROWS > 0 THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END)
 WHERE t.table_schema = 'sanitizedfooname';
```

And for completeness sake, the following is the table desc:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| table_name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| needs_migration | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| already_done    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Obviously I'm not *trying* to update the information schema, but it seems to think I am. Also, I could have sworn I had run the query before and it worked, but now I question my sanity, I mean memory. This is on AWS RDS, MYSQL 8 if that makes any diff.

So... why does it say paper-jam when there is no paper-jam?

Comment: must be a aws thing https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3636749aaacc02bfa25b3cf7ca5d85b8

Comment: @basha04 --  I did, and basically it sounded like the answer to that was `SET @@session.optimizer_switch := 'semijoin=off';` which does NOT change the error message I get.

Comment: the query you posted can't be the same as it has no for update

Comment: @nbk It's the same query. I got it to run on a different RDS instance with the same setup. Clearly something is borked on this instance, though I have no idea HOW I got it into this state. I'm going to reboot it and see what happens. At the end of the day it's going to be some sort of end user error -- I would just like to know what I did.

Comment: maybe it is another build, as amazon compiles it own releases

Comment: @nbk good call, they are different versions. 8.0.23 let's me run it while 8.0.21 gives the error. Going to 'upgrade' the minor version and see what happens.

Comment: @nbk - that solved it, thanks!